# GIT: не-merge удаленных файлов (комфортный маленький бренч)

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch, git-merge

Делаю новую ветку от рабочей ветки с кучей файлов. Мне эта куча файлов не нужна - удаляю. Работаю с нужными.
А когда делаю мердж в рабочую ветку - там все файлы удаляются, ведь я же их удалил в своей ветке.

Как заставить гит "забыть" о существовании ненужных мне файлов или же заставить "забыть" об их удалении. А, возможно, решение находится не в этом моменте, а в моменте создания новой ветки...

В общем: как создать комфортный маленький бренч, который содержит не все файлы, а только нужные мне? Чтобы потом при слиянии рабочие файлы перезаписывались, а все остальные (которые я не трогал) - оставались в целостности.

Comment: Вы хотите странного. Ну не нужны файлы, не открывайте их. Но возможно вам нужен [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) хотя он больше про гигантские репозитории типа ядра линукса и больших монорепозиториев

Comment: @Alexey Ten как я могу "не открывать" ненужные мне файлы, если их больше 1000 и они разбросаны по всем папкам, включая нужные мне. Я просто теряю свои файлы в куче ненужного мне мусора.

Comment: Похоже у вас в приниципе плохая организация репозитория и нужно решать эту проблему, что бы нужные файлы лежали максимально компактно. Например в том же ядре какой-нибудь разработчик видео-драйвера может не смотреть на файлы для разработки сети, потому что они в разных папках

Comment: Ну и см. первый комментарий про sparse checkout

Comment: По поводу организации: к сожалению, я не тру-кодер, который пишет программы. А бд-разраб, который должен где-то хранить свои sql и elt файлы. И, к сожалению, я не директор ДИТ, чтобы решать архитектурные вопросы - поэтому архитектура такая, какая она есть: надо складывать файлы в кучу папок и в одной папке будут лежать файлы от разных разработчков.

Comment: а по поводу "sparse checkout": я так понимаю, что теоретически он мог бы решить мою проблему. Но из-за архитектурных ограничений - что все файлы должны лежать в строго определенных папках - мне придется писать не паттерны, а сами пути до каждого из файлов.

Comment: можно отдельным коммитом удалить ненужные файлы, потом докоммитать изменения в нужные. перед мержем сделать ребейз и коммит с удалением файлов выбросить

Comment: но по мне так проблема надумана. проще уже не обращать внимания на "ненужное"

Comment: Ну у вас же есть какой-то принцип по которому вы удаляете или оставляете файлы.

Comment: @Alexey Ten
принцип есть: показатель надо залить в схему SCHM - значит, надо создать скрипт DB/SCHM/s.MY_METRICA.sql (или править его, если это доработка и файл уже существует). Остальные файлы в моей текущей задаче не нужны - они "удаляются".

Comment: @PashaPash попробуй найти свой файл в папке, если там еще лежит 30 файлов. А затем перейти в другую папку среди 20 папок, чтобы найти второй файл среди еще 40 таких же.

Comment: @AntispamAntispam у меня на проекте 20-ть девелоперов как-то свои файлы находят. "Остальные файлы в моей текущей задаче не нужны - они "удаляются"" - ну ок, вы сами себе придумали принцип, сами от него страдайте Ж) git на такой принцип не рассчитан, к сожалению

Comment: ¿А почему бы не сделать отдельный репозиторий с нужными файлами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не забросил поиск ответа и нашел: `git checkout --orphan`

Если создать ветку с параметром орфан, то она "забудет" свое прошлое, и удаление файлов пройдет беспоследственно - их как будто и не было.

Тогда можно просто мерджить ветку в другие без потери тех файлов, которые реально не трогали.